# Angularjs: Show/hide values in separate div, when click on any cell in table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, angularjs

In following demo I am showing more than one value in single cell of table. If any particular row's cell has one value then nothing to do. But if it has more than one value, then we can hide and show the values. **Hiding and showing are happening in same cell.**

I want to do this in **separate div**. So that If number of value are more the It won't effect the table.like It open some div and show all values from cell inside that dev..

Please see the demo, Last row has more than one value for **ID** column. I **want to show this expansion in separate** **DIV**

Please see [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9zkp5mr1/)

**View**

```
 <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="todolist in todolists">
        <td>
             <span ng-repeat="list in todolist.id| limitTo: showMore ? todolist.id.length:1">
     <a target="_blank" href="{{ 'http://'+common_url}}{{list}}"> {{list}}</a>
 </span> 
     <a ng-show="todolist.id.length>1 && showMore==false" ng-click="showMore = true">....show {{todolist.id.length-1}} more</a>
     <a ng-show="showMore==true" ng-click="showMore = false">....show less</a>
        </td>
        <td>{{todolist.bill_number}}</td>
        <td>{{todolist.location}}</td>
        <td><a target="_blank" href="{{ 'http://' + todolist.url}}">Download Invoice : <i title="Download Invoice" style="padding-left:5px;cursor:pointer;color:black;" class="fa fa-download"></i></a> </td>

      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
```

**Controller**

```
.controller('ctrl', function($scope) {
        $scope.showMore=false;
        $scope.common_url="localhost:8000";
        $scope.todolists = [{
          "id": "id_584",
          "customer_id": 2,
          "url": "url",
          "bill_number": "123",
          "location": "from_location"
        }, {
          "id": "id_122",
          "customer_id": 3,
          "url": "url",
          "bill_number": "123",
          "location": "from_location"
        }, {
          "id": "id_128",
          "customer_id": 4,
          "url": "url",
          "bill_number": "123",
          "location": "from_location"
        }, {
          "id": "id_805",
          "customer_id": 5,
          "url": "url",
          "bill_number": "123",
          "location": "from_location"
        }, {
          "id": "id_588",
          "customer_id": 6,
          "url": "url",
          "bill_number": "123",
          "location": "from_location"
        }, {
          "id":"id_115,id_114,id_116,id_130,id_118,id_119",
          "customer_id": 7,
          "url": "url",
          "bill_number": "123",
          "location": "from_location"
        }]
                $scope.todolists.forEach(function(item){                    
          var multiple_orders = item.id.split(',');
          item.id=multiple_orders;
        });
      });
```

Comment: You can set fixed width to the first column, so showing and hiding will affect only the height of the row but not the width `tr td:first-child {width: 40%;}`

Comment: What are expected results and how do they differ from demo?

Comment: @charlietfl  like It open some div and show all value from cell inside that dev..

Comment: just pass the whole `todolist` object to a function in `ng-click`. In scope make it `selectedItem` or whatever you want to call it. Then template that div for same variable

Answer (score 1):

```
<td style="word-wrap:break-word">
             <span ng-repeat="list in todolist.id| limitTo: showMore ? todolist.id.length:1">
     <a target="_blank" href="{{ 'http://'+common_url}}{{list}}"> <div>
       {{list}}
     </div></a>
 </span> 
     <a ng-show="todolist.id.length>1 && showMore==false" ng-click="showMore = true">....show {{todolist.id.length-1}} more</a>
     <a ng-show="showMore==true" ng-click="showMore = false">....show less</a>
        </td>
```

Try this

Answer (score 0):

Replace with your 'Show More" ng-click with this:

```
ng-click=" assignToDiv(todolist) "
```

and the function will be:

```
$scope.assignToDiv = function(arr){
    $scope.showInDiv = arr;
};
```

And then bind your div to the showInDiv (then show the div as desired):

```
<div>
      <a ng-repeat=" id in showInDiv.id " > {{ id }}</a> 
</div>
```